# Make an array completely empty

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to completely empty this array:

```cs
    string[] strNumbers = new string[3] { "1", "2", "3" };
```

So it looks like this in the end:

```cs
    strNumbers = {}
```

Comment: Arrays are constant size in C#. Consider using `List<string>`.

Comment: It is an exercise for school and I have to use arrays

Comment: You can this `Array.Clear(strNumbers, 0, strNumbers.Length);` Just be aware it will clear by putting `null` on all element.

Comment: `strNumbers = new string[0]`?

Comment: You can use `strNumbers = new string[] {};`.

Comment: @CodeNotFound would there be any difference with just `Array.Clear(strNumbers)`?

Comment: @GuruStron I used your solution. I don't even know how I didn't think of that.

Comment: `Array.Resize(ref strNumbers, 0);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko which is effectively `strNumbers = new string[0]` in this case as far as I understand, no?

Comment: @Guru Stron: I vote for `strNumbers = Array.Empty<string>();` in order not to create a *new instance* on each `new string[0];` Here is an academic question, but in real life `Array.Empty<string>()` is preferable, that's why let's teach a good technique.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko to that I can agree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't use this

```
 strNumbers = new string[3] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.Clear` will set elements of array to the default values (`null` for `string`) but will keep the size of array. Just new up the array:

```cs
strNumbers = new string[0];
```

Or even better:

```cs
strNumbers = Array.Empty<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you are asking.

1. **Create a new array with no elements**

   ```
   string[] strNumbers = new string[0];
   ```

   or

   ```
   string[] strNumbers = Array.Empty<string>();
   ```

   `strNumbers.Length` will be zero
2. **Create a new array but leave contents empty**

   ```
   string[] strNumbers = new string[3];
   ```

   contents will be three `null` values
3. **Take an existing array and remove all the elements**

   Arrays in C# are of fixed size. You cannot add or remove elements from arrays. If you need variable size arrays, use `List<string>` or some other collection type.
4. **Take an existing array and set the contents to their default values**

   ```
   for(int i=0; i<strNumbers.Length; i++)
   {
       strNumbers[i] = default(string);
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   Array.Clear(strNumbers, 0, strNumbers.Length);
   ```